# Germany: What happens if you lose your job on a national D visa?

Tags: visa, germany, working-visas, work-permit

Let us say you moved to Germany on a national D visa with job offer. The plan was to get a blue card once inside Germany. But your employer terminates your employment very soon **before you apply for your blue card**.

What happens then? Can you stay in Germany till the full validity of your national D visa (which can be 1 year)? Can you stay and find another job? If you have to leave, what is the grace period?

Comment: Sorry for bringing this up again. This just happened to me. I came in with National Visa D and on my first day, I lost my job. How do I inform the foreigners office about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a German National Visa (D) is issued, a decision has already been made.

The **remarks** field will contain a text stating was has been granted:

- **§18b AufenthG**

would be the text for a Blue-Card.

The visa allows you to enter the country to take up residence and is issued, in most cases, for 3 months.

After your arrival, you report to the Immigration Office where the residence permit will be issued (which replaces the visa) and the actual card will be produced (which can take some time).

After reporting to the Immigration Office  you can start working.

---

If you lose your job, your residence permit will switch from §18b to §20:

- [§20 - Skilled workers seeking employment - AufenthG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0570)

which gives you (up to) 6 months to find a new job.

Once you have found a job, that fulfills the Blue Card conditions, the residence permit will switch back to §18b.

Comment: Thank you Mark! When they decide how much time I get (6 months or less) do they already have all the information about me (my degree, profession, skill, etc) or do I have to again produce all this to them? Do I have to take an appointment at the Auslanderbehorde if I get fired to understand how much time I get?

Comment: Yes, they will have that information,since the consulate sends them that when you made the original application. It is the local Immigration office that makes the decison to issue the visa (**not** the consulate). Yes, for the first 2 years you must inform them of any changes.